# How to solve $-\frac{1}{2}gt^2\sin \theta=x$ when $x$ equals $0$

Tags: classical-mechanics

This given equation, $-\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2\sin \theta=x$  should describe the path of a ball rolling up an incline with initial speed $v_0$.

The question is: **how long will the ball take to return to its starting point?**

It is obvious that the equation must be solved for $x=0$, which has two solutions, according to my solution manual:
for $t=0$ and for $t=\dfrac{2v_0}{g\sin \theta}$

However, I do not understand how the second solution is obtained?

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: If $x=0$, the equation has only one solution $t=0$. You should check your resolution: where did the $v_0$ term go?

Comment: This is because the equation really should be:
$$x=\color{red}{v_0\cdot t}-\frac{1}{2}gt^2\sin(\theta)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motion equation should be

$$x=-\frac 12gt^2\sin (\theta)+v_0t $$

and for $x=0,$ we get the desired solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The correct expression should be

$$v_0t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2\sin \theta=x$$

and thus for $x=0$

$$v_0t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2\sin \theta=0\implies t=0 \quad \lor \quad t=\dfrac{2v_0}{g\sin \theta}
$$